# script only outputting one file name of many to new file

Tags: bash

I am trying to output the name of every file that in it's last line has "#FIXME"  into a new file.

```
find -type f -print0 |while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME && echo "$file" > newlog.log 
done
```

This only outputs one file containing "#FIXME" to newlog.log when there are actually mutliple files.
Could anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the FIXME comments are always the last line in the file — no stray blank lines at the end of a file?  If the `FIXME` lines aren't reliably the last line, you could simplify your life with `find . -type f -exec grep -l -e FIXME {} + > newlog.log`.

Comment: Only the last file is found in the log afterwards, isn't it? Wouldn't it be necessary to use `>> newlog.log` to also keep all the previous output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have setup a loop which executes this line in the middle for many files:

```
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME && echo "$file" > newlog.log
```

This line however creates and writes the file "newlog.log" each time,
which results in the already existing content being overwritten each time, with only one file name. This gave you the impression that only one file name was written to the log file. It happens to be the last one.

In order to get a list of all the written file names, i.e. to keep all of the content, you need to append to the existing loggile, instead of overwriting it.
To do that, use `>>` instead of `>`.

```
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME && echo "$file" >> newlog.log
```

This creates the need to consider the content of the log file before executing the script.
Either you are fine with always also keeping the content of the previous script execution,  which I guess you are probably not, or you can make sure the file has no content.

You can either delete the file and create it freshly. Or you do once use the `>` intentionally. This would allow you to make something of a headline for the list, e.g. containing the date of the creation and the path you executed it in.

Comment: I always think that detailed explanation is appreciated. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Rather than using `>> newlog.log` inside the loop, it's probably better to redirect the loop as a whole to `newlog.log`, by putting the `> newlog.log` after the `done`.

Comment: @ruakh That is an interesting approach. May I recommend to make an answer of it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append to the file, not overwrite. ANd this

```
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME && echo "$file" > newlog.log
```

should be

```
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME && echo "$file" >> newlog.log
```

Comment: thank you! i looked up the difference between > and >> and for some reason i didn't see it

Comment: @comearound `>` write to the file from begin (erase previous content) `>>` append to the existing content of the file